# How to navigate between files in electron with fixed navigation on left side?

Tags: electron

I have a project on **Electronjs** for account management. I'm using ***photonkit*** . Sample of the UI is as:
[image]

Now, how can I navigate between other html files without refreshing the whole page (as SPAs)?

N.B.: I may use jQuery but I don't want to use JS frameworks like **Angular** etc.

Comment: Just use react and react-router, you are making your life more complicated with jQuery...

Comment: So, is it react that will suit best with Electron?